# Encoding and decoding an email

Tags: c#, decode, encode

I am trying to encode an email, send a link based on the token created and then decode the email, but my output is never the same as the input. I was wondering what I am doing wrongly here:

```
    public IActionResult ResetPasswordLink(string email)
    {
        // Hash the email address
        byte[] emailBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(email);
        byte[] hashedBytes;
        using (var sha256 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create())
        {
            hashedBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(emailBytes);
        }
        string hashedEmail = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedBytes);

        string token =WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashedEmail));

        string resetLink = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}/resetpassword/{token}";

        // Decode the token to get the hashed email
        byte[] hashedEmailBytes = WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(token);
        string decodedEmail = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hashedEmailBytes);

        Console.WriteLine("Original email: " + email);
        Console.WriteLine("Decoded email: " + decodedEmail);

        //SendEmail(email, resetLink);

        Console.WriteLine("Token when encoding: " + token);

        return Ok(resetLink);

    }
```

Comment: Are you aware that you can't un-hash a Hash ?

Comment: TBH i wasnt, thank you for the heads up!

Comment: You are calling `Convert.ToBase64String()` but at no point do you call `Convert.FromBase64String()`

Comment: @MatthewWatson they call `WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode()`, but anyway, that's not the real problem here.

Comment: @jps Yes, but they called `WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode()` which is what the call to `WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode()` is decoding. They still need to either remove the `Convert.ToBase64String()` or add a corresponding `Convert.FromBase64String()` otherwise the code won't work, even if they fix the other issue. There are two problems here, one of which is this. Someone else mentioned  the other issue already, so I didn't need to repeat it.

Comment: But you can see that Jeevan's answer has removed the extraneous call to `Convert.ToBase64String()` so all is well.

Comment: @MatthewWatson ok, sorry, I missed the second layer of encoding with `Base64UrlEncode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are hashing the email address before encoding it, but you are trying to decode the encoded token directly to the hashed email address. Since the hashing process is irreversible, you won't get the original email address back from the hashed email.

```
public IActionResult ResetPasswordLink(string email)
{
    // Encode the email address
    byte[] emailBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(email);
    string encodedEmail = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(emailBytes);

    // Encode the email directly without hashing
    string token = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(emailBytes);

    string resetLink = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}/resetpassword/{token}";

    // Decode the token to get the encoded email
    byte[] decodedEmailBytes = WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(token);
    string decodedEmail = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedEmailBytes);

    Console.WriteLine("Original email: " + email);
    Console.WriteLine("Decoded email: " + decodedEmail);

    Console.WriteLine("Token when encoding: " + token);

    return Ok(resetLink);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jeevan, apparently the fact that i was unware that i cant unhash a hash was the biggest problem!